# Talend export and import a job

Tags: talend

In Talend (particularly MDM Studio TOS and TOP 4.2.3 on Windows 7), how can I export a job so that it can be imported on a separate machine, into an existing workspace.

Comment: 4.2.3 is a long way back so not 100% sure but at least in 5+ the top menu bar has icons for importing and exporting that launch the import and export wizards

Comment: @ydaetskcoR It appears I needed to check *overwrite existing items* under the *Import items* dialog.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To export a Job:

- Right click the Job, and select *Export Job*.
- To the right of *To archive file*, click *Browse* to choose the destination and name for the Job ZIP archive.
- Select the *Job Version*.
- Set *Export type* to *Anonymous Job*.
- Check all *Options*.
- Click *Finish*.
- A ZIP archive will be created at the selected destination containing the Job.

To import a Job:

- Right click *Job Designs* under the *Repository* section, and select *Import items*.
- Click *Select archive file*, *Browse*, and select the Job ZIP archive.
- Optionally, check *overwrite existing items* if you're importing an existing Job.
- Check the Job under the *Items List* tree.
- Click *Finish*.
- The Job should now appear under *Job Designs*.

Comment: This is according to which Talend version?

Comment: @GadaaDhaariGeek In my question: "MDM Studio TOS and TOP 4.2.3".

Comment: Ok. I asked this because the version which I am using doesn't have exact options as you have mentioned here. Anyway, thanks.